# Outputting elements in a row using a loop

Tags: dart

I am looking to output a series of Widgets within a for a loop however cannot get it to work beyond a basic example as shown below.

This works:

```
    Row(
      children: <Widget>[
        for (var i = 0; i < 6; i++) Text(i.toString())
      ],
    ),
```

This does not work.

```
    Row(
      children: <Widget>[
        for (var i = 0; i < 6; i++) {
          Text(i.toString())
        }
      ],
    ),
```

Answer (score 0):

When you want to use a for-loop to render multiple widgets, as of [Dart 2.3](https://medium.com/flutter-community/whats-new-in-dart-2-3-1a7050e2408d), it only supports a for-loop without curly braces.

Not sure about the full reasoning why. A "bracketless" for-loop only loops the statement immediately following it, so maybe it was intended to enforce that rule.

Comment: Thank you. How do I have multiple lines of code within a for loop?

Comment: Collection-for accepts only an *expression* as its body, not even a full statement, and curly braces are used to create a block of statements. I highly recommend reading https://medium.com/dartlang/making-dart-a-better-language-for-ui-f1ccaf9f546c for background.